# Is default return variable of function always allocated?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-optimization

I'm interested in how default variable named the same as the function is implemented.

- Is `Sum` always allocated even if I am not using it? (see `case 1`)
- If I choose another variable (`Total` in `CASE 3`), is it used instead of `Sum`?

Are the following 3 equivalent cases also equivalent when compiled? Or is some superior to others?

```
' EQUIVALENT CASES

' CASE 1
Function Sum(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
    Return a + b
End Function

' CASE 2
Function Sum(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
    Sum = a + b
End Function

' CASE 3
Function Sum(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Total As Integer
    Total = a + b
    Return Total
End Function
```

As I read somewhere, functions compiling to less than 32 bytes are inserted inline. I wonder whether in some cases, I might end above or below the limit just because of the chosen notation.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the compiler makes all three of those the same thing. Case 3 might "waste" time creating the variable though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I renamed your functions to Sum1, Sum2, and Sum3, respectively and then ran them through LinqPad.  Here is the generated IL:

```
Sum1:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  ldarg.2     
IL_0002:  add.ovf     
IL_0003:  ret         

Sum2:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  ldarg.2     
IL_0002:  add.ovf     
IL_0003:  stloc.0     // Sum2
IL_0004:  ldloc.0     // Sum2
IL_0005:  ret         

Sum3:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  ldarg.2     
IL_0002:  add.ovf     
IL_0003:  stloc.1     // Total
IL_0004:  ldloc.1     // Total
IL_0005:  ret
```

It appears that Sum2 and Sum3 result in the same IL.  Sum1 appears to be more efficient since it puts the result of the operator directly onto the stack.  The others must pull the result off the stack into the local variable and then push it back onto the stack!

Comment: Very interesting to see that the compiler doesn't optimize them, especially Case 2. I'm glad I always use Case 1, saving those nanoseconds! :P

Comment: @Keith - This IL comes from LinqPad.  It is possible that when compiled by VS in Release mode or when JITted, that it may be optimized as you suggest.

Comment: @Keith - it might be not only about variable creation, but also about inlining. Is body of fucntion inserted inline or is there a regular call made with putting parameters on stack and all that stuff...

Comment: Ah, okay. I assumed LinqPad (never used it) mimicked what VS does. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a VB.NET expert, but I do know something about C#. In C#, this kind of code isn't allowed. You should always `return` a value, else the code won't compile.

I guess VB.NET circumvents this by something like this in C#:

```
T Sum = default(T);

...

return Sum;
```

It defaults the value of `Sum`, which in the case of an `int` is `0`.

According to this logic, the variable gets allocated, for reference types, this means there will be no allocation, since they are defaulted to `null`.

Looking at the IL:

```
.method public static int32  Test() cil managed
{
  // Code size       3 (0x3)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 Test)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldloc.0
  IL_0002:  ret
} // end of method Module1::Test
```

from this `Function`:

```
Function Test() As Integer

End Function
```

You will see `init`, which initializes a variable (allocates it) and `ldloc`, which is an call to obtain the value of a variable, hence, it must be allocated.

Comment: I know that. This is why I tagged this question **vb.net**, not just **.net** or **c#**.

Comment: What do you mean. What do you know?

Comment: I commented when the answer was only about C#. This is why I initially downvoted it. I would be happy if we can stay at VB because C# and VB compilers might be completely different on approach in these cases. Moreover, C# does not support `CASE 2`. If you can, please remove C# part of the answer.

Comment: @miroxlav: They are different, but they become the same IL, so there must be some for of uniformity.

Comment: Sure, I meant approach to optimization etc. As you can see from Chris' answer, VB.NET doesn't bother to optimize `CASE 2` nor `CASE 3` to the short form of `CASE 1`. Would be interesting to see what C# compiler produces for C# equivalents of `CASE 1` and `CASE 3`. Will they end like VB.NET's optimized `CASE 1` or like `CASE 2`?

Comment: In what mode did he compile the assemblies? In release mode? Then I am very sure they will be inlined.

Comment: Good comment +1. I don't have an answer but I today learned that generally it matters whether helper variable is used or not. VB.NET compiler doesn't remove them in the above cases.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't think so. Compiling with optimization does not remove variables that could be inlined, but the JIT compiler may do so.

Comment: @sloth: It won't remove them, but it might just end up all the same (case 3 most questionable).

Comment: @miroxlav *but I today learned that generally it matters whether helper variable is used or not.* Please don't draw the wrong conclusion from this. Using a helper variable does only matter in terms of readabilty, not execution speed since it will probably be eliminated from the JIT compiler.

Comment: @sloth - but if I understand correctly, preliminary inlining (see bottom of the question) is done in VB.NET compiler [edit: typo corrected]